# Why was this question closed and deleted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions, closed-questions

I asked this question yesterday: [Why functions are slow than statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63979370/why-functions-are-slow-than-statements?noredirect=1#comment113135732_63979370) But this question was closed in 30 minutes saying debugging details required and deleted after about 4 hours. This was a question about performance of statements. Someone commented that my question was closed because my testing build was not optimized. But in the question I clearly stated that non optimized build not using functions are faster than optimized build using functions. This question had the following information:

> With no optimization and without function, it takes about 2.65 and with optimization and function, it takes 3.51 minutes.

Why was this question closed and deleted?

Comment: You neglected to show your disassembly of the test cases.

Comment: The comments explain. But also: Research before considering posting a question. So research basics of how code execution time is related to code. If you want to know about specific code you need to give other information that was requested including specifics of how you came to run it.

Comment: @MartinJames How do I get that?

Comment: Consider that the question lacks details why you are surprised that "statement" is faster than "function + statement".

Comment: [Question formation in English](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t4yWEt0OSpg&t=1m49s) (QUASM).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

On Stack Overflow, questions and their answers in general are expected to be about practical programming problems; those kind of problems tend to be useful for many visitors to come. Questions that don't fit that criteria are subject to votes of the following kinds: down, close and delete.

The C++ tag is notorious with its knowledgeable experts and the vigorous maintenance of quality.

Performance is hard. There are so many variables that results probably vary between setups. You're presenting a use case in your question that is at best interesting from a theoretical point of view but hardly useful in a practical sense.

To the question *Why are functions slow*, my answer would be: because they do more work. And then you continue to ask *Should I use macros instead?*. I'm not a C++ dev, but that seems a weird solution that, as far as I understand macros, can only help you out in specific scenarios and certainly not to replace all functions with it.

Reading the comments, it becomes apparent what is lacking from your question. First, the used compiler and its settings are missing. Then it turns out that you're performance testing without the proper compiler settings. And when users try your example code it turns out the compiler outsmarts all of us.

Back to basics: Your question is missing a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including exact setup and a proper test-approach for comparing results across compilers / CPU, it lacks a practical context and seems more like a fundamental misunderstanding of functions and macros then anything else. I also expect this statement could apply: [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/80092/99854). The commenters, close and delete voters all thought nothing good would come out of that question.

If you do have actual/real-world working code where you're looking for (performance) improvements you could check if the site [Code Review.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) would accept that question.

As I read your question I would say it is more driven by curiosity then anything else. By itself wondering about behavior of code is not a bad thing. Turning it into a good question needs a lot more context and a practical use case.

Comment: Surely you've been around enough C++ programmers to know that the answer to, "Should I use macros instead?" is almost always "No." :-) It's not about premature optimization. It's just about the wrong tool for the job.